# Clicking on a li twice before it console logs using vanilla js?

Tags: javascript

I'm new at JavaScript so I hope this isn't a dumb mistake. I have an unordered list with 5 li elements. I was trying to get the text from a clicked li. (console.log). But it will only console.log on the second time I click the li. I've tried many things but nothings working, can someone help me? Thank you.

Here is my code...

```js
var mainUl = document.querySelector('#main-list').addEventListener('click', liPick);
// //console.log(mainUl);

function liPick() {
  var ele = document.querySelectorAll('#main-list li');
  ele.forEach(function(item) {
    item.onclick = function(e) {
      //var myText = this.innerText;
      //console.log(myText);
      //alert(this.innerText);
      //var myDiv = document.getElementById('#whatclicked');

      console.log(this.innerText);

    }
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=divice-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatable" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
  <script src="./js/script.js" defer></script>
  <title>JavaScript Selectors</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <ul id="main-list">
      <li class="list-items">Item 1</li>
      <li class="list-items">Item 2</li>
      <li class="list-items">Item 3</li>
      <li class="list-items">Item 4</li>
      <li class="list-items">Item 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="whatclicked"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const els = document.querySelectorAll('#main-list li');

els.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', liPick, false)

})

function liPick() {
  alert(this.innerText)
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <ul id="main-list">
        <li class="list-items">Item 1</li>
        <li class="list-items">Item 2</li>
        <li class="list-items">Item 3</li>
        <li class="list-items">Item 4</li>
        <li class="list-items">Item 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the query selector properly. right now it wont set it as long as the variable `mainUl` is not accessed.
Try going from this

```
var mainUl = document.querySelector('#main-list').addEventListener('click',liPick);
```

to this

```
document.querySelector('#main-list').addEventListener('click',liPick);
```

that will set it as soon as the document is loaded

Answer (score 2):

This will work, just run the function you are already attaching events inside of it, no need for another eventListener

```js
 function liPick() {
   var ele = document.querySelectorAll('#main-list li');
   ele.forEach(function(item) {
     item.onclick = function(e) {
       //var myText = this.innerText;
       //console.log(myText);
       //alert(this.innerText);
       //var myDiv = document.getElementById('#whatclicked');

       console.log(this.innerText);
     }
   })
 }
 
 liPick()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=divice-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatable" content="ie=edge">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
      <script src="./js/script.js" defer></script>
      <title>JavaScript Selectors</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="container">
        <ul id="main-list">
          <li class="list-items">Item 1</li>
          <li class="list-items">Item 2</li>
          <li class="list-items">Item 3</li>
          <li class="list-items">Item 4</li>
          <li class="list-items">Item 5</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="whatclicked"></div>
    </body>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you assign the click event listener to the `li` inside another click event.

Move the code currently inside the liPick function- out of the function or call the liPick function on a different timing.

Answer (score 2):

you have two click events in your code, that's what's causing the problem.  remoe one and you're good to go.

```js
var mainUl = document.querySelector('#main-list').addEventListener('click',liPick);
// //console.log(mainUl);

function liPick(){
var ele = document.querySelectorAll('#main-list li');
ele.forEach(function(item) {
    
        var myText = item.innerText;
        //console.log(myText);
        //alert(this.innerText);
        //var myDiv = document.getElementById('#whatclicked');
        

        console.log(myText);

   
});
}
```

```html
<ul id='main-list'>
<li>one</li>
<li>two</li>
<ul>
```